# microsoft navision nav 2009, selection of radiobutton

Tags: microsoft-dynamics

I am using tree radion buttons. But The third option 'order maken' will not be selected.

I have this as code:

```
END ELSE BEGIN
  IF CONFIRM('Er is te weinig voorraad voor een artikel, wilt u verder gaan?',TRUE) THEN 
  BEGIN

    Selection := STRMENU(Text000,3);
    IF Selection = 1 THEN BEGIN
      LocFrmQuoteInfo.FncSetFields(CodCounterUser,OptCounterDocType,CodCounterDocNo,RecCust);
      LocFrmQuoteInfo.RUNMODAL;
    END;
    IF Selection = 2 THEN
      EXIT;
    IF Selection = 3 THEN BEGIN
         Options := Text000;
    Selected := DIALOG.STRMENU(Options, 3, Text000);
    MESSAGE(Text000, Selected);
     // FncCreateOrder();
      //LocFrmQuoteInfo.RUNMODAL; 
     //EXIT;
  END;
```

and this as the variable:

```
&Offerte maken,,&Terug naar overzicht,Order maken
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ,, in your optionstring takes up a value, as such the &Terug naar overzicht, is number 3 and 'order maken' is actually number 4 in the list.

Removing the ,, should get your numbers to line up with how your code works, but assuming that the ,, should be in the code below is the direct change to make:

```
END ELSE BEGIN
IF CONFIRM('Er is te weinig voorraad voor een artikel, wilt u verder gaan?',TRUE) THEN 
BEGIN

  Selection := STRMENU(Text000,3);
  IF Selection = 1 THEN BEGIN
        LocFrmQuoteInfo.FncSetFields(CodCounterUser,OptCounterDocType,CodCounterDocNo,RecCust);
    LocFrmQuoteInfo.RUNMODAL;
  END;
  IF Selection = 3 THEN //Updated to 3
    EXIT;
  IF Selection = 4 THEN BEGIN  //Updated to 4
       Options := Text000;
  Selected := DIALOG.STRMENU(Options, 3, Text000);
  MESSAGE(Text000, Selected);
   // FncCreateOrder();
    //LocFrmQuoteInfo.RUNMODAL; 
   //EXIT;
END;
```

You might want to consider refactoring the code using a [CASE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd339070.aspx) Statement.

```
IF CONFIRM('Er is te weinig voorraad voor een artikel, wilt u verder gaan?',TRUE) THEN 
  BEGIN

CASE DIALOG.STRMENU(Text000,3) OF
  1: BEGIN
    //Work for Section 1
    //LocFrmQuoteInfo.FncSetFields(CodCounterUser,OptCounterDocType,CodCounterDocNo,RecCust);
    //LocFrmQuoteInfo.RUNMODAL;
    MESSAGE('&Offerte maken');
  END;
  3: BEGIN
    //Add Work for Section 2
    MESSAGE('&Terug naar overzicht');
    EXIT;
  END;
  4 : BEGIN
    //Add Work for option 4
    //FncCreateOrder();
    //LocFrmQuoteInfo.RUNMODAL;
    MESSAGE('Order maken')
  END;
  ELSE BEGIN
    //Catch anything Strange
    ERROR('Invalid Option Selected');
  END;
END; //CASE
```

END;

I feel there are a a few advantages to this over your code, it will catch any exceptions or modifications to the string with the default case (the ELSE at the bottom).  Also only the specific selections will execute as your code does not have ELSE statements it will evaluate all of the IF's on every user selection.